# Customizing libPhoneNumber from Google

Tags: java, libphonenumber

I'm using `libphonenumber` from Google. I want to customize some data of this library U cloned the Project then I modify in     `resources/PhoneNumberMetadata.xml`.
Then I changed the Mobile Number related to Egypt from 10 to 15 Number.

```xml
<territory id="EG" countryCode="20" internationalPrefix="00" nationalPrefix="0"
               mobileNumberPortableRegion="true">
      <availableFormats>
        <numberFormat pattern="(\d)(\d{7,8})" nationalPrefixFormattingRule="$NP$FG">
          <leadingDigits>[23]</leadingDigits>
          <format>$1 $2</format>
        </numberFormat>
        <numberFormat pattern="(\d{2})(\d{6,7})" nationalPrefixFormattingRule="$NP$FG">
          <leadingDigits>
            1[35]|
            [4-6]|
            8[2468]|
            9[235-7]
          </leadingDigits>
          <format>$1 $2</format>
        </numberFormat>
        <numberFormat pattern="(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})" nationalPrefixFormattingRule="$NP$FG">
          <leadingDigits>[189]</leadingDigits>
          <format>$1 $2 $3</format>
        </numberFormat>
      </availableFormats>
      <generalDesc>
        <nationalNumberPattern>
          [189]\d{8,9}|
          [24-6]\d{8}|
          [135]\d{7}
        </nationalNumberPattern>
      </generalDesc>
      <!-- Subscriber numbers starting with 5 are also permitted for the area codes 040, with 5, 6
           and 7 for the area code 050, with 5 and 7 for 082, with 6 for 084, with 7 for 086 and
           092 and with 5 and 6 for 96. -->
      <fixedLine>
        <possibleLengths national="8,9" localOnly="6,7"/>
        <exampleNumber>234567890</exampleNumber>
        <nationalNumberPattern>
          (?:
            15\d|
            57[23]
          )\d{5,6}|
          (?:
            13[23]|
            (?:
              2[2-4]|
              3
            )\d|
            4(?:
              0[2-5]|
              [578][23]|
              64
            )|
            5(?:
              0[2-7]|
              5\d
            )|
            6[24-689]3|
            8(?:
              2[2-57]|
              4[26]|
              6[237]|
              8[2-4]
            )|
            9(?:
              2[27]|
              3[24]|
              52|
              6[2356]|
              7[2-4]
            )
          )\d{6}
        </nationalNumberPattern>
      </fixedLine>
      <mobile>
        <possibleLengths national="15"/>
        <exampleNumber>100123456712345</exampleNumber>
        <nationalNumberPattern>1[0-25]\d{13}</nationalNumberPattern>
      </mobile>
      <tollFree>
        <possibleLengths national="10"/>
        <exampleNumber>8001234567</exampleNumber>
        <nationalNumberPattern>800\d{7}</nationalNumberPattern>
      </tollFree>
      <premiumRate>
        <possibleLengths national="10"/>
        <exampleNumber>9001234567</exampleNumber>
        <nationalNumberPattern>900\d{7}</nationalNumberPattern>
      </premiumRate>
    </territory>
```

Then I build the Project then I take the Jar in my Project to depend on the New Jar but still see that Mobile Number is 10 Numbers not 15
that is the Code I wrote

```java
public static void main(String argc[])
    {
         PhoneNumberUtil phoneUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();
            try {
                Phonenumber.PhoneNumber egyNumber = phoneUtil.parse("152234567891234", "EG");
                boolean isValidNumber = phoneUtil.isValidNumber(egyNumber);
                System.out.println(isValidNumber);
            } catch (NumberParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
```

This code return `FALSE` but it should return `TRUE`.

**Note**: The Library use Binary File for each Country, but I think it's encoded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i found that Google provides  a way to customize the Metadata related to any Country 
through some steps you can find them here

https://github.com/google/libphonenumber/blob/master/making-metadata-changes.md